# Can't use UINavigationButton in Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uinavigationbar

I"m trying to disable the rightButton in my navigationBar every time I am sync my database. I subclassed the navigationBar, since I need to move the items a little bit upwards.

Now I try to disable the right Button during the layoutSubviews. I am able the get the UIView which is of type UINavigationButton. Once I try to cast the UIView to UINavigationButton I get the error: "Use of undeclared type 'UINavigationButton'". So I thought I just need to import another library, but it seems that this class is not reachable? Or does anyone know what to import?

This is my current approach, since I can read the dynamic type and cast it to string, I use that for deciding which on I need to move.

```
let navigationBarItems = self.subviews
    var lableInserted = false
    var buttons:[UIView] = []
    for navigationBarItem in navigationBarItems{
        print(String(navigationBarItem.dynamicType))
        if String(navigationBarItem.dynamicType) == "_UINavigationBarBackground"{
            if  syncBarDataSource != nil{
                navigationBarItem.frame.origin.y = bounds.origin.y + CGFloat(syncBarDataSource!.barHeight) - CGFloat(maxHeight/2)
                navigationBarItem.frame.size.height = bounds.size.height + CGFloat(maxHeight)
            } else {
                navigationBarItem.frame.origin.y = bounds.origin.y - CGFloat(maxHeight/2)
                navigationBarItem.frame.size.height = bounds.size.height + CGFloat(maxHeight)
            }
        }
        if String(navigationBarItem.dynamicType) == "UINavigationButton" || String(navigationBarItem.dynamicType) == "UINavigationItemButtonView"{
            buttons.append(navigationBarItem)
        }
        if let lable = navigationBarItem as? UILabel{
            lableInserted = true
            lable.text = syncBarDataSource.text
            if syncBarDataSource!.barHeight > 0{
                lable.hidden = false
            } else {
                lable.hidden = true
            }
        }
    }
```

But if I want to cast like

```
navigationBarItem as? UINavigationButton
```

I get the described error

Comment: Please share your code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried UIBarButtonItem instead of UINavigationItem ?

Comment: Probably to late, but I did, and it didn't work out. I just used that way